# Proof of this Theorem of Identity and inverse elements in Zm

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, inverse, automata

Theorem: Let m ∈ N{1}, and let a, b ∈ Um. Show carefully that a⊗m b has a
multiplicative inverse in Zm.

The set Um is closed under ⊗m; i.e., for any a, b ∈ Um, we have a ⊗m b ∈ Um.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Define N{1}, U, Um and circle ×.